# Capturing of video buffering instances

Tags: jmeter, loadrunner

I want to capture the video buffering instances(like the time duration of the buffering) for a particular video. How can I achieve this using Load Runner/Jmeter tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Apache JMeter, you can use this plugin which computes buffering:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/load-testing-mpeg-dash-jmeter-ubik-videostreaming-plugin/
- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/ubikloadpack-http-live-streaming-plugin-jmeter-videostreaming-mpegdash/

It handles HLS, MPEG-DASH and MS Smooth streaming video formats.

Disclaimer: we provide this solution

Comment: Hi, I browsed through the URL and have subscribed for a trial version of the plugin.It's been 3 days and I haven't received any mails regarding the same.Could you please look into it?

Comment: I checked, trial has been sent to you . Can you check your spam folder ? if issue persists, can you send a mail to contact at ubik-ingenierie.com ? thanks

Comment: I checked even the spam folders and couldn't find it though.Could you please verify it once again from your side and send it to the registered email id

Comment: Hello,You should now have received the trial. Contact our support in case of any issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You capture this in a single user session.  These actions (buffering) are local processing.

Comment: Video buffering is purely a client side action.   In client-server some processing is server based, some is client based.  You ask how to use tools which are designed to reproduce server flows, to show server under load, to monitor servers to answer a question with a client basis that should be answered at every single functional validation point in architecture, development and functional testing before you begin to answer questions on a server basis.